# Angular. Not all components found with @ViewChild

Tags: angular

I've read a lot of Q/A about this topic but no one match my case

This is part of my component code

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'
import { Modal } from '../../modal.component'
import { ChargingPoint } from '../../d4c.model'

// Sub-components
import { D4CDevChargingPointsTableComponent } from './d4c.chargingpoints-table.component'
import { D4CDevChargingPointFormComponent } from './d4c.chargingpoints-form.component'
import { D4CDevChargingPointsSearchFormComponent } from './d4c.chargingpoints-search-form.component'

// Data service
import { D4COperationService } from '../../services/d4c.operation.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'd4c-chargingpoints',
  templateUrl: './templates/devices/chargingpoints/d4c.chargingPoints.template.html',
  providers: [D4COperationService]
})
export class D4CDevChargingPointsComponent {

    @ViewChild( D4CDevChargingPointsTableComponent )
    chargingpoints_table: D4CDevChargingPointsTableComponent;

    @ViewChild( D4CDevChargingPointFormComponent )
    chargingpoint_form: D4CDevChargingPointFormComponent;

    @ViewChild( D4CDevChargingPointsSearchFormComponent )
    chargingpoint_search_form: D4CDevChargingPointsSearchFormComponent; 

    @ViewChild( Modal )
    chargingpoint_modal: Modal;

    chargingPoints: ChargingPoint[];

    constructor( private operationService: D4COperationService ) {};

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        this.operationService.getChargingPoints().then( chargingPoints => {
            this.chargingPoints = chargingPoints; 
        });
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log( "ChargingPoint Form: " + this.chargingpoint_form );
    }
...
```

This is the component template:

```
<h1>Estaciones de recarga</h1>

<d4c-chargingpoints-search-form (filter)="filter()" (clean)="cleanFilter()">
</d4c-chargingpoints-search-form>

<d4c-chargingpoints-table
    [chargingPoints]="chargingPoints"
    (onAddButton)="add()"
    (onEditButton)="edit($event)"
    (onRemoveButton)="remove($event)">
</d4c-chargingpoints-table>

<modal>
    <span class="modal-title" >
        Estación de Recarga
    </span>
    <d4c-chargingpoints-form 
        (ok)="formOk()"
        (cancel)="formCancel()"
        class="modal-content">
    </d4c-chargingpoints-form>
</modal>
```

When I stop in `ngAfterContentInit` or in `ngAfterViewInit` only the `Modal` control is defined all other are still undefined.

Sub-components are correctly shown. For example the table show all loaded 'charging points' but is not referenced by `chargingpoints_table`.

I have other controls with exactly the same structure that works fine. I don't find the difference with the other nor the cause of ViewChild not to work.

Why are those references to child components undefined and how can I solve it? Thanck you.

Comment: Are you sure the components are instantiated? Did you register them in `declarations` of the module?

Comment: As I said subcomponents are correctly showed in screen, for example the table (including its data). Those are registered in module declaration.

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker? I have never seen that `@ViewChild()` didn't work.

Comment: Solved! it was very weird. For any reason in browser cache were js files with 'chargingPoint' or 'chargingpoint' in name. Once I have resolved it and unified names the problem disapeared.